# How to merge key values within dictionaries if they have a common key-value pair?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have a list of dictionaries,

```
list = [
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'abcde'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'fghijkl'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'bbbbbb'},
    {'hostname': 'b', 'ipaddr':'xxxx'}
]
```

How do I make it so that the output looks like this:

```
outputList = [
    {
        'hostname': 'a',
        'ipaddr': ['abcde', 'fghijkl', 'bbbbbb']
    },
    {
        'hostname': 'b',
        'ipaddr':'xxxx'
    }
]
```

---

**Edit**:
Before this step, I have filtered a JSON list of selected hostnames

```
['hostname1', 'hostname2', 'hostname3', 'hostname4' ......]
```

Then, given a huge JSON list of dictionaries (called "list" above), I have to sieve out the respective hostnames and ipaddresses, preferably grouped according to hostnames so that I can parse it elsewhere easily.

Comment: Tip: `{'a': ['abcde', ...], 'b': ['xxxx']}`…

Comment: I agree with @deceze, it would be much easier to work with the data if you also put the cases with 1 ipaddr value into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
inputList = [
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'abcde'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'fghijkl'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'bbbbbb'},
    {'hostname': 'b', 'ipaddr':'xxxx'}
]

outputList = {}
for d in inputList:
    od = outputList.setdefault(d['hostname'], {})
    od.setdefault('hostname', d['hostname'])
    od.setdefault('ipaddr', []).append(d['ipaddr'])
outputList = sorted(outputList.values(), key=lambda x: x['hostname'])

assert outputList == [
    {
        'hostname': 'a',
        'ipaddr': ['abcde', 'fghijkl', 'bbbbbb']
    },
    {
        'hostname': 'b',
        'ipaddr':['xxxx']
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for!

Comment: @axaxa ,  please upvote each answer that was helpful to you. If one answer was fully satisfactory, please accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
lists = [
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'abcde'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'fghijkl'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'bbbbbb'},
    {'hostname': 'b', 'ipaddr':'xxxx'}
]

hostnames = set([d['hostname'] for d in lists])

outputlist= list()

for hostname in hostnames:
    od = {
        'hostname': hostname,
        'ipaddr': []
        }
    for d in lists:
        if d['hostname'] == hostname:
            od['ipaddr'].append(d['ipaddr'])
    outputlist.append(od)
```

This solution assumes that all the dictionaries inside `lists` will contain the key `'hostname'`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for!

Comment: Welcome, if it solves your problem then you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) it as answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
list_1 = [
{'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'abcde'},
{'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'fghijkl'},
{'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'bbbbbb'},
{'hostname': 'b', 'ipaddr':'xxxx'}
]

out_list = []

for each_dict in list_1:
    if out_list:
        for out_dict in out_list:
            if out_dict['hostname']==each_dict['hostname']:
                out_dict['ipaddr'].append(each_dict['ipaddr'])
            else:
                temp_dict = {}
                temp_dict['hostname']=each_dict['hostname']
                temp_dict['ipaddr']=[each_dict['ipaddr'],]
                out_list.append(temp_dict)
    else:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict['hostname']=each_dict['hostname']
        temp_dict['ipaddr']=[each_dict['ipaddr'],]
        out_list.append(temp_dict)

print out_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'abcde'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'fghijkl'},
    {'hostname': 'a', 'ipaddr':'bbbbbb'},
    {'hostname': 'b', 'ipaddr':'xxxx'}
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in lst:
    d[item['hostname']].append(item['ipaddr'])

output = [dict(zip(['hostname', 'ipaddr'], item)) for item in d.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for!