# Find same keys and merge in list of dicts? Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, finance

This code produces a list of dictionaries.

```
 watchlist = r.get_open_option_positions()
    for x in watchlist:
        print('Symbol: {}, Average Price: {}, Quantity: {}'.format(x['chain_symbol'], 
    x['average_price'], x['quantity']))
```

Output:

```
Symbol: PG, Average Price: -46.5714, Quantity: 35.0000
Symbol: PG, Average Price: 33.7142, Quantity: 35.0000
Symbol: MSFT, Average Price: -80.0000, Quantity: 6.0000
Symbol: MSFT, Average Price: 53.0000, Quantity: 6.0000
```

How do I code the following criteria:

```
if symbol is the same and quantity of both symbols is the same, then subtract average prices and multiply by quantity
```

So for example the result should look like:

```
Symbol: PG, Average Price: (-12.8572 * 35), Quantity: 35.000
Symbol: MSFT, Average Price: (-27 * 6), Quantity: 6.000
```

Comment: Are you looking to group only consecutive items with this criteria, or everything in the watchlist?

Comment: Everything in the watchlist would be better

Comment: Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868437/how-to-merge-key-values-within-dictionaries-if-they-have-a-common-key-value-pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set up a dict (a defaultdict for convenience) to keep track of each group:

  ```
  groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ```
- Iterate over `watchlist` add each `x` to a group:

  ```
  for x in watchlist:
      groups[(x["chain_symbol"], x["quantity"])].append(x)
  ```
- Iterate over each group and sum the prices (it's the same thing as subtracting them here really):

  ```
  for group_key, group in groups.items():
      final_price = sum(x["average_price"] for x in group)
      print(group_key, final_price)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the price values for each combination of symbol and quantity in a dictionary like this:

```
product = {}

for x in watchlist:
    if not x['chain_symbol'], x['quantity'] in product.keys():
        product[x['chain_symbol'], x['quantity']] = []
    product[x['chain_symbol'], x['quantity']].append(x['average_price'])
```

Then you iterate over all the products (Combinations of symbol and quantity) and you can implement the operations you desire over all the existing prices. The folowing code does a a mean, but you can change it to what you need.

```
for k in product.keys():
    symbol = k[0]
    quantity = k[1]
    all_the_prices = product[k]
    price = sum(all_the_prices)/len(all_the_prices) # Change here to your operation
    print('Symbol: {}, Average Price: {}, Quantity: {}'.format(symbol, price, quantity)
```